# Игнорирование JUNIT теста при условии через Assume.assumeFalse()

Tags: java, spring, junit

Имеется тестовый класс:

```
abstract public class AbstractServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    boolean isJdbc() {
        return Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("jdbc");
    }

    @ClassRule
    public static ExternalResource summary = TimingRules.SUMMARY;

    @Rule
    public Stopwatch stopwatch = TimingRules.STOPWATCH;

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    public <T extends Throwable> void validateRootCause(Runnable runnable, Class<T> exceptionClass) {
        try {
            runnable.run();
            Assert.fail("Expected " + exceptionClass.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.assertThat(getRootCause(e), instanceOf(exceptionClass));
        }
    }
}
```

Имеется класс-наследник, в котором нужно проигнорировать один тест при условии isJdbc():

```
public abstract class AbstractMealServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MealService service;

    @Test
    public void createWithException() throws Exception {
        Assume.assumeFalse(isJdbc());
        validateRootCause(() -> service.create(new Meal(null, of(2015, Month.JUNE, 1, 18, 0), "  ", 300), USER_ID), ConstraintViolationException.class);
        validateRootCause(() -> service.create(new Meal(null, null, "Description", 300), USER_ID), ConstraintViolationException.class);
        validateRootCause(() -> service.create(new Meal(null, of(2015, Month.JUNE, 1, 18, 0), "Description", 9), USER_ID), ConstraintViolationException.class);
        validateRootCause(() -> service.create(new Meal(null, of(2015, Month.JUNE, 1, 18, 0), "Description", 5001), USER_ID), ConstraintViolationException.class);
    }
}
```

Как избежать прохождение теста при выполнении условия

`Assume.assumeFalse(isJdbc());`

без появления ошибки

`org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: got: <false>, expected: is <true>`?

Comment: нет, этот тест нужно игнорить именно в случае выставленного JDBC профиля

Comment: `if(!isJdbc()) { тут ваш тест }`

Comment: То, что свалилось `org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException` не значит, что свалился сам тест. Проект же в итоге собирается корректно?